# How to get Last sunday date in Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap Datepicker and I want to set the date for current/last Sunday.The code below is showing the content form   $date to $date1.

```
if (!isset($_POST['new-date'])){
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');// I want to set last/current sunday 
    date here.
    $date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$date +6 day"));
    $d = explode(" ",$date);
    $d1 = explode(" ",$date1);
} else {
    $d[0] = $_POST['new-date']; 
    $d1[0] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$d[0] +6 day"));
}
$d[0] = $_POST['new-date'];
```

The ['new-date'] may be any day/date from the calendar but It should select the last Sunday of that particular week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be written in PHP, rather than JavaScript, so I'm not sure how relevant the question title or tags are.

```
// Check if the day of the week is a Sunday. If yes, use today's date. If no, use last Sunday's date
$timestamp = date('N') == 7 ? strtotime('today') : strtotime('last sunday');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);

die($date);
```

**Edit**

You asked in the comments how you can find last Sunday for any given date.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($_POST['date'] ?? 'today');
$sunday = (date('N', $timestamp) == 7) ? $timestamp : strtotime('last sunday', $timestamp);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $sunday);

die($date);
```

Comment: Thanks , could you please also let me know how I can use  here to pass the Sunday' date to that variable 
 $d[0] = $_POST['new-date'];

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking. Why can’t you just assign the date? `$d[0] = $date;`?

Comment: I want to pass any random date and then it should return the sunday's date for that particular week.eg:- if we pass the 15/12/2017 then it should return 10/12/2017, which is sunday for that week.

I cant use $d[0] = $date; because it will return sunday of present week. But i want for any random week.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you read the docs on `strtotime` and `date`, you'll see that you can seed the values with a timestamp.